# IIDs and PDF of X+Y

Tags: probability, random-variables

I had an exam with the following question:

Let X and Y be iid random variables with the following distribution

f(x) = $\lambda$exp(-$\lambda$x) if $x\geq0$

= $0$ otherwise.

Find PDF of $X+Y$

Since X and Y are independent,

f(x,y) = f<sub>1</sub>(x) * f<sub>2</sub>(y) = $\lambda$<sub>1</sub>exp(-$\lambda$<sub>1</sub>x) * $\lambda$<sub>2</sub>exp(-$\lambda$<sub>2</sub>y)

Let $Z$ = $X+Y$

f<sub>$Z$</sub>(z) = $\int_0^\infty$$\lambda$<sub>1</sub>exp(-$\lambda$<sub>1</sub>x) * $\lambda$<sub>2</sub>exp(-$\lambda$<sub>2</sub>(z-x))

= $\lambda$<sub>1</sub>$\lambda$<sub>2</sub>exp(-$\lambda$<sub>2</sub>z)/($\lambda$<sub>1</sub> - $\lambda$<sub>2</sub>)

I haven't used the identically distributed part of the random variables. I have been told the limits are wrong and the limit should be from $\int_0^z$. I didn't understand this.What did I mi(e)ss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral's endpoints are wrong.  Note that $f_2(z-x) = \lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2 (z-x))$ only when $z - x \ge 0$.

As for the "identically distributed" part, that says $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$.  So you certainly won't want a division by $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$ in the answer...

Comment: so the PDF would be :  z$\lambda^2$exp(-$\lambda$z)